# Draw app is Lagging when adding shapeLayer into views layer in Swift / IOS

Tags: ios, swift, draw

I am creating a **drawing app**. This app allows user to draw on the view. i name that view drawing view in the code given below. To create this app I have use **BeizerPath** and **ShapeLayer**, whenever user touches the screen the **UIBeizerPath** and **CAShapeLayer** is initialized.  The Problem with this app is after some drawing view gets Lagged. I cannot figure out what is happening. Is there better way to **optimize** this app?

```
CanvasViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var verticalScrollView: UIScrollView!
    var lastPoint:CGPoint?   // var mutablePath:CGMutablePath?
    var drawLine:UIBezierPath?
    var shapeLayer:CAShapeLayer?
    let dropDown = DropDown()
    var shape:CAShapeLayer?
    let listOfDropDownMenu:[String] = ["Create New Canvas","Save","Change Color"]
    var presenter: CanvasModuleInterface?

    // MARK: IBOutlets
     @IBOutlet weak var drawingView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var showColorViewControllerDropDownButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    // MARK: VC's Life cycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setup()
        self.verticalScrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }

    // MARK: IBActions

    // MARK: Other Functions

    @IBAction func ShowColorViewControllerAction(_ sender: Any) {
         self.dropDown.anchorView = self.showColorViewControllerDropDownButton
         self.dropDown.dataSource = self.listOfDropDownMenu
        self.dropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index: Int, item: String) in
            switch index{
            case 0:
              self.createNewView()
            case 1:
              self.saveTheCanvas()
            case 2:
             self.presentToColorViewController()

            //self.presentColorController()
            default:
                print("out of order !!!")
            }

        }
        self.dropDown.show()
    }

    private func createNewView(){
        //Mark: - create new canvas
        self.drawingView.layer.sublayers!.forEach { (layers) in
            layers.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
    }
    private func presentToColorViewController(){
        // Mark : - naviagate to color view controller.


    }
    private func saveTheCanvas(){
        // Mark: - save the drawing

    }

    private func setup() {
        // all setup should be done here
    }
    private func presentColorController(){
        let colorSelectionController = EFColorSelectionViewController()
        let colorNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: colorSelectionController)
        colorNavigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        colorNavigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        colorNavigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
        colorSelectionController.delegate = self
        colorSelectionController.color = self.view.backgroundColor ?? UIColor.white

        if UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.compact == self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass {
            let doneButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
                title: NSLocalizedString("Done", comment: ""),
                style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done,
                target: self,
                action: #selector(dismissViewController)
            )
            colorSelectionController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton
        }
        self.present(colorNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @objc func dismissViewController(){
        //##ask confusion.....
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

// MARK: CanvasViewInterface extension CanvasViewController: CanvasViewInterface {
     } extension CanvasViewController: EFColorSelectionViewControllerDelegate{
    func colorViewController(_ colorViewCntroller: EFColorSelectionViewController, didChangeColor color: UIColor) {

    } } extension CanvasViewController{

    //Mark: - this extension contains function for drawing the circle.
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touches begin")

        self.drawLine = UIBezierPath()
        self.shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        //       self.mutablePath = CGMutablePath()

        if let touchesPoint = touches.first{
            self.lastPoint = touchesPoint.location(in: self.drawingView)
         }

    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
         //        self.drawingView.layer.sublayers!.forEach { (layer) in //            print(layer) //        }
      //  print(self.drawingView.layer)

    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){ //        print("\(self.drawingView)") //        print("\(self.drawingView.layer.sublayers)")

        var nextPoint:CGPoint?
        if let touchesPoint = touches.first{
            nextPoint = touchesPoint.location(in: self.drawingView)
            guard let lastLinePoint = self.lastPoint , let nextLinePoint = nextPoint else{return}
            self.drawLineInDrawingView(from: lastLinePoint, to: nextLinePoint)
        }
        if let newPoint = nextPoint{
        self.lastPoint  = newPoint
        }
    }
    func drawLineInDrawingView(from:CGPoint,to:CGPoint){
        drawLine!.move(to: CGPoint(x: from.x, y: from.y))
        drawLine!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: to.x, y:  to.y))
        shapeLayer!.path = drawLine!.cgPath
        shapeLayer!.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer!.lineCap = .round
        shapeLayer!.lineWidth = 100
        self.drawingView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer!)    //     print(self.drawingView.layer.sublayers)
    }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what `CanvasViewController` you are are using, one can't entirely answer your question correctly, but I will answer, assuming it works similar to any regular UIView in iOS.

There are a few things I can point out to improve performance:

First of all, don't add the same `ShapeLayer` over and over inside `drawLineInDrawingView(from:CGPoint,to:CGPoint)` to the drawing view, instead do so only once in `touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)` and store a reference to it.

Secondly your `drawLineInDrawingView(from:CGPoint,to:CGPoint)` should look like this:

```
func drawLineInDrawingView(from:CGPoint,to:CGPoint){
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)

    drawLine!.move(to: CGPoint(x: from.x, y: from.y))
    drawLine!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: to.x, y:  to.y))
    shapeLayer!.path = drawLine!.cgPath
    shapeLayer!.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shapeLayer!.lineCap = .round
    shapeLayer!.lineWidth = 100
    shapeLayer!.setNeedsDisplay()

    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

So in conclusion: Upon touchesBegan() you add the shapeLayer and store a reference to it. Inside touchesMoved, you call the drawLineInDrawingsFunction.
Your drawLineInDrawingsFunction, only updates your Shapelayer with `shapeLayer.setNeedsDisplay()`.

Putting your transformation inside

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
/**Your transformation here**/
CATransaction.commit()
```

Is only there to stop your View from automatically animating changes, and instead show them immediately.

I hope this helps.

Comment: where should i write this self.drawingView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer!) method ?

Comment: @junky You could write that line of code inside the `touchesBegan` method, after `self.shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()`

Comment: is there more option to optimize this code and make my drawing app more smooth and fast ?

Comment: @junky There might be some specifics for the canvas view you are using. But since I don't know how or when the performance goes down at the moment, you could create only one ShapeLayer for every color, and then concatenate each new path of the same color into one path. 
Also, you could think of a clever way to minimise the amount of points used to create a line. For example, when you're done drawing the line, have a task remove unnecessary points and redraw the previous line. Straight segments for example can be removed with only one start and endpoint.